# Canvas is not editable in mobile browser

Tags: html, mobile, web, html5-canvas, drawing

i have to develop a website where user comes and have some area for free drawing.

like some sketch and then save the image on server. so I chooses canvas.. since we can easily draw line, points based on mouse (x,y) changes

But problem came when tested on mobile browser like samsung galaxy tab, e.g., using its pen; canvas is not editable. seems like mouse down doesn't trigger.

```js
ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
$('#myCanvas').mousedown();
```

or any other javascript api for free drawing that works for both desktop and mobile will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the "touch" events from jQuery Mobile? [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp)

Comment: yes.. it doesn't work for canvas